# CSS - Change font color of a string variable

Tags: html, css, reactjs, colors, fonts

I am trying to change color of the variable of the logged in username.

`userData.name` is a simple string returned from the API:

[image]

The issue is how it looks on the UI (you can barely see the name because it has black font):

[image]

Does anyone know how to add styles to `userData.name` variable so that it changes the font to white or some other color?

Thank you!

Comment: You could also try giving it a CSS class (logged-in, etc.) and then style that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to wrap it in a paragraph or something similar and then you can style that element

```
{auth ? (<p style={{color: 'white'}}>{userData.name}</p>) : <Button />}
```